# wordpress - Отдельный URL для плагина

Tags: php, wordpress

Добрый день, вопрос такой, можно ли сделать отдельную страницу под плагин средствами плагина. Без создания страницы в админке и шаблона к нему.

Допустим перехватить хуками или еще как то?

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить хук `init` и функцию обработки `REQUEST_URI` в код вашего плагина:

```
function my_plugin_init() {
    if ( stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/my_url/') === 0 ) {
        // Тут делаем редирект или что-то ещё, что должен делать плагин
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_plugin_init');
```